# POI - Java - Updating a Cell using for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, apache-poi

I am trying to write in a column of an excel sheet a list of values using a for loop.

The Idea is that every 3 sheets beginning at 1, my code writes two possibles values.

For example:

```
for ( q = 0 ; q < my_xls_workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); q=+2)
{
    HSSFSheet my_worksheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(1);
    HSSFCell cell = null; 
    cell = my_worksheet.getRow(m).getCell(4);
    cell.setCellValue(myStoredValue[m][2]);
    input_document.close();
    FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new    File("C:\\Framework.xls"));
    my_xls_workbook.write(output_file);
    output_file.close();
}
```

Where row  `m` is already a stored value, cell 4 is first cell of column where I want to input the values and `my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(1);` is the sheet where it will start to write the values. According to the for loop it will increment by 2 every time.

But when my code is running I get an `NullPointerException` Can POI work in that way or am I doing something wrong?

I am learning java so I am not an expert. Also excuse me about my english.

Comment: On what line do you get the `NullPointerException`?  You are looping with `q` but you aren't using `q` anywhere.

Comment: `q=+2` is probably a typo. I think you meant `q+=2`.

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop control:

```
for ( q = 0 ; q < my_xls_workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); q=+2)
```

You are looping with `q` (hopefully this is an `int`?), but your increment is `q=+2`, which is interpreted as `q` `=` `+2` -- which always SETS `q` to positive 2. If you really want to only check every 2nd sheet, this should be `q += 2` or `q = q + 2`.

You should then change the way you are getting your sheets: `my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(1)` should use your looping variable `q`, like so: `my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(q)`. Otherwise you are simply getting the sheet at index 1 every single time, which may not exist and would therefore probably be returned as `null`. According to `HFFSWorkbook` documentation, `HFFSWorkbook#getSheetAt(int)` is 0-based, so your loop is correct but your program is grabbing index 1, the 2nd sheet.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the `m`th `Row` doesn't exist or that the index `4` `Cell` does not exist.  The `getRow` and `getCell` methods return `null` if they haven't been created yet.  Check if they're `null` and create them with `createRow(m)` and/or `createCell(4)` if needed.